# VB.net text -> Excel conversion (with extensive formatting required after conversion)

Tags: vb.net, vba

I'm creating a program in VB.net that does the following:

At a high level I receive a file in email, put the attachment in a monitored folder, import the text file to excel, format the excel, and then email the excel file to a list of recipients.

Here is my plan:

1. Completed: Outlook VBA to monitor all incoming email for specific    message. Once message is received drop attached .txt file in a    specific network folder.
2. Completed: (VB.net) Monitor folder, when text file is added begin    processing
3. Not Complete: (VB.net) Import text file to Excel
4. Not Complete: (VB.net) Format Excel Text file. (add in a row of data,    format column headers with color/size, add some blank columns, add    data validation to some of the blank columns that allow drop down    selections)
5. Completed: (VB.net) Save file.
6. Completed: (VB.net) Send file to list of recipients.

Obviously the items above that are not complete are the bulk of the work, but I wanted to get some advice on what some of you think would be the best way to approach something like this. The import and formatting of the file are causing me some problems because I just can't decide what would be the most efficient way to do this.

What I've thought of so far:

- The way stated above. Import to excel -> format
- Having a template excel that contains all of the formatting already done for me and attempting to transition the data to this document (no clue if/how I can do this). Is it even feasible? Have the template already created and then import the text file to a new excel file, then transition that data to the excel template?

Something I thought about, in terms of formatting the document, was to record a macro of me doing all of the formatting that I'm going to need and then attempt to convert that macro into my vb.net code, but I'm not sure if that will work. I will need to verify that the text file comes in the EXACT format every time correct?

I really appreciate any advice/suggestions that anyone is willing to give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use http://epplus.codeplex.com/

It allows you to create an Excel file from scratch, without having to start Excel itself. Automating Excel will make the process slow and it lacks robustness (Excel process can hang or not close properly).

In addition, using a .Net library allows you to run it on a server or so where no Excel is installed. (Next step would be to inspect the mailbox via POP, IMAP or the Exchange API, so that part doesn't have to be run on a client machine either)

Comment: Sweet, Thanks Dirk!  I'm going to go look at it now.  I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Dirk - would you suggest that I import the text file to Excel first and then apply all of my formatting?

Comment: not at all, I would load the data from the text file in memory (maybe using a library such as http://www.filehelpers.com/ if it is a common format) and then create the Excel from memory.

Comment: Ok, great!  I'm going to look into filehelpers.com for the import portion and then do all of my formatting using EPPlus.  Thanks a ton for all of the advice and help from everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate Excel files, I can recommand you the [NPOI library](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) found on CodePlex. It has several advantages over OLE-automation:

1. NPOI is not dependent on a specific Excel version.
2. Excel (or any other Office component) need not to be installed.
3. It is faster.

It works with both .XLS and .XLSX files.

Comment: Thanks Olivier, I will take a look at this as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw(v=vs.100).aspx

You can also just use the Interops from MS to interact with Excel, Outlook, Word, etc. They're not difficult at all to use. I'm not familiar with CodePlex, so that may be a better route or an easier one. I just wanted to provide you with an alternative.

Comment: Thanks Yatrix - I think I'm going to end up using something like EPPlus because of ease of use.

Comment: Cool. Don't forget to give the correct answer an up vote and accept it. Best of luck, dude.

Comment: Thanks again Yatrix!  I marked the one I am using as the right answer, but any time I try to upvote I am told that I don't have enough reputation to upvote anything.  Oh well, that will come with time/use I'm sure

Comment: Keep coming back. This is one of the best internet communities you'll find. Very helpful folks around here.

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft Office 2010 Interops you can not generate Office files from .net applications anymore.

You can manipulate data from existing Excel files so you need templates(your 4th point). Then Excel allows you to query some databases. You may be able to simulate one with your folder, otherwise I suggest to convert your .txt files into some databases. (3rd point)

If you do use an older version, you can crate your Excel files by loading them into an instance of Excel and manipulating them as you wish.

By the way I supposed your attached files would have some sort of format.

Comment: Well, the attached file is a text file that is set for import with a delimiter of '#'.  So I need to import a delimited text file and then apply some pretty extensive formatting.  I'm looking at EPPlus and I think I'll be able to use that for the formatting.  Now I just need to figure out how to import the delimited text file.

Comment: If you replace those #'s with tabs, you can "paste" it in, I bet. Used to do that with the Interops. Just put a carriage return at the end of the line so it jumps in the sheet. It'll behave like you selected a group of cells and pasted them. Just pick the cell your paste starts.

Comment: For reading delimited text files, I would definitely recommend the FileHelpers Library: http://www.filehelpers.com/. I think it can even export to Excel using Interop, but since you need to do some formatting as well, epplus is probably still the better choice for that.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a third party software called excel writer.  May not be what you are looking for becauseit needs to be license, but it is very fast and the clients does not have to wait for a chart or a data output.  Because we have that tool, have not try anything else.